# Sending multiple files to Laravel backed using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm using a multi-step form in Vue.js to send multiple files to a Laravel backend. The form gives the user the ability to add multiple users to the database. Each user requires a file to be uploaded along with it.

Files are initially stored in state using Vuex. Each file is pushed to a **files** array in store.js

When the user submits the form, the files array looks as follows:
[image]

When the user submits the form I'm adding all the individual form data including the files array to a new FormData() object like so:

```
let fd = new FormData();
// append each file
for( var i = 0; i < store.state.files.length; i++ ){
  let file = store.state.files[i];

  fd.append('files[' + i + ']', file);
  console.log(file);
}
// append rest of form data
fd.append('appointments', store.state.appointments);
fd.append('business_details', store.state.business_details);
fd.append('business_names', store.state.business_names);
fd.append('directors', store.state.directors);
fd.append('share_amount', store.state.share_amount);
fd.append('shareholders', store.state.shareholders);
```

Once all the form data is added I use Axios to send the form data to my Laravel backend.

```
axios.post('/businesses', fd, {
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
})
.then(response => {
   console.log(response);
   this.completeButton = 'Completed';

})
.catch(error => {
   console.log(error)
   this.completeButton = 'Failed';
})
```

Inside my Laravel **BusinessController** I then want to `Log::debug($_FILES)` to see what files were sent along but all I get is an empty array.

```
[2018-10-05 16:18:55] local.DEBUG: array (
)
```

I've checked that the headers I'm sending includes `'multipart/form-data'` and that I'm appending all my form data to new FormData() but I cannot figure out why the server receives an empty $_FILES array.

**UPDATE 1:**
If I `Log::debug($request->all());` I get:
[image]

If I try to store the objects in that file like so:

```
foreach ($request->input('files') as $file) {
  $filename = $file->store('files');
}
```

I get the following error:

```
[2018-10-06 09:20:40] local.ERROR: Call to a member function store() on string
```

Comment: What do you see when you do `dd($request->all())` ?

Comment: @ysfkaya Updated the question. This is what I get. Still cannot access the files to store them

Comment: Ok. It isn't seems converted files in vue.js. I will share a function for this converting.

Comment: Is there a reason why this wouldn't work. I've followed several tutorials and technically this should be the right way to do this.

Comment: I think Laravel's `Container` structure is itself methods with converting from the `Requests`

Comment: And you should be use `$request->files('files')` or `$request->file('files')` methods

Answer (score 0):

Try this case:

```
var objectToFormData = function (obj, form, namespace) {

var fd = form || new FormData();
var formKey;

for (var property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {

        if (namespace) {
            formKey = namespace + '[' + property + ']';
        } else {
            formKey = property;
        }

        // if the property is an object, but not a File,
        // use recursivity.
        if (typeof obj[property] === 'object' && !(obj[property] instanceof File)) {

            objectToFormData(obj[property], fd, property);

        } else {

            // if it's a string or a File object
            fd.append(formKey, obj[property]);
        }

    }
  }

  return fd;

};
```

**Reference : [objectToFormData](https://gist.github.com/ghinda/8442a57f22099bdb2e34)**

Axios :

```
 axios.post('/businesses', fd, {
          transformRequest: [
             function (data, headers) {
                  return objectToFormData(data);
              }
          ]
 })
.then(response => {
   console.log(response);
   this.completeButton = 'Completed';

})
.catch(error => {
   console.log(error)
   this.completeButton = 'Failed';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
 fd.append('files[' + i + ']', file);
```

To this:

```
 fd.append('files[]', file);
```